# wp-insert-post execute from server?

Tags: posts, development-strategy

I wanted to ask for help.

I am working on a project to develop a program to publish a post to many wordpress sites that aren't on a multisite network but are all on the same server.

the requirements for this program is that it does not take delay for publishing so the post should be sent once onto the server and the server will have to add the post to many sites and the program also needs to filter the publishing of the post to sites with the requested categories.

I Have started to work on it. i found 2 solutions to adding a posts to a wordpress site:

1. wp-insert-post and other functions in the wordpress documentation
2. xml-rpc

for now i understand the program will be slipt into 3 parts:

1. an interface where the sites with the similar category will be selected to the post.
2. a program on the server that receives the publish request and the chosen sites to submit it to.
3. a program to publish to the website.

if anyone has any tips and ideas to help or has worked on a similar project please help.

Comment: have you considered using the REST API instead? Note that you need to write your question so that it's specific, and can be answered with facts, and you need to be able to mark an answer as the canonical solution. This isn't a discussion forum thread

Comment: how would the Rest API aid me i don't really have a strong foundation in wordpress development, and wanted to ask for advice in this matter

Comment: the REST API is newer and more capable than XMLRPC, and follows standard conventions and tooling, after all REST APIs are not unique to WordPress, even Google has REST APIs, and there's chrome extensions, apps, and tools that predate WordPress' REST API. XMLRPC is there for legacy reasons. You should look into the WordPress REST API, there's extensive documentation and examples in the official WP developer docs